# Required field 'uncompressed_page_size' was not found in serialized data! Parquet

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark, parquet

I am getting below error while trying to save parquet file from local directory using pyspark. 
I tried spark 1.6 and 2.2 both give same error

It display's schema properly but gives error at the time of writing file.

```
    base_path = "file:/Users/xyz/Documents/Temp/parquet"
    reg_path = "file:/Users/xyz/Documents/Temp/parquet/ds_id=48"
    df = sqlContext.read.option( "basePath",base_path).parquet(reg_path)
    out_path = "file:/Users/xyz/Documents/Temp/parquet/out"
    df2 = df.coalesce(5)
    df2.printSchema()
    df2.write.mode('append').parquet(out_path)

 org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: can not read class org.apache.parquet.format.PageHeader: Required field 'uncompressed_page_size' was not found in serialized data! Struct: PageHeader(type:null, uncompressed_page_size:0, compressed_page_size:0)
```

Comment: what hadoop distro?

Comment: I am running it from my local machine. So I just have installed spark I did not install Hadoop.

Comment: what spark version do you have locally?

Comment: I tried this with both spark 1.6 and 2.2.0

Comment: What Java version did you install?

Answer (score 2):

In my own case, I was writing a custom Parquet Parser for Apache Tika and I experienced this error. It turned out that if the file is being used by another process, the ParquetReader will not be able to access `uncompressed_page_size`. Hence, causing the error.

Verify if other processes are not holding on to the file.

Answer (score 1):

Temporary resolved by the spark config:

```
"spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreParquet": "false"
```

Although it would has extra cost, but a walkaround approach by now.